# Add-Migration hangs on using context - no error

Tags: c#, .net-core, entity-framework-core, entity-framework-migrations

I'm having an issue with my package manager console.  I run `Add-Migrations name -Verbose` and it hangs after finding the database context.  Note - this is not my initial migration, that worked fine, this is a new migration.  Also, this is a console app, not a web app, so I'm not worried about the error concerning hosting.

```
> PM> Add-Migration owner -Verbose  
Using project 'GWMyBot.Database'.  
Using startup project 'GWMyBot'.  
Build started...  
Build succeeded.  
C:\Program Files\dotnet\dotnet.exe exec --depsfile  C:\Users\parab\Source\Repos\GWMyBot\GWMyBot\bin\Debug\netcoreapp2.2\GWMyBot.deps.json --additionalprobingpath C:\Users\parab\.nuget\packages --additionalprobingpath C:\ProgramData\Xamarin\NuGet --additionalprobingpath "C:\Program Files\dotnet\sdk\NuGetFallbackFolder" --runtimeconfig C:\Users\parab\Source\Repos\GWMyBot\GWMyBot\bin\Debug\netcoreapp2.2\GWMyBot.runtimeconfig.json C:\Users\parab\.nuget\packages\microsoft.entityframeworkcore.tools\3.1.3\tools\netcoreapp2.0\any\ef.dll migrations add owner --json --verbose --no-color --prefix-output --assembly C:\Users\parab\Source\Repos\GWMyBot\GWMyBot\bin\Debug\netcoreapp2.2\GWMyBot.Database.dll --startup-assembly C:\Users\parab\Source\Repos\GWMyBot\GWMyBot\bin\Debug\netcoreapp2.2\GWMyBot.dll --project-dir C:\Users\parab\Source\Repos\GWMyBot\GWMyBot.Database\ --language C# --working-dir C:\Users\parab\Source\Repos\GWMyBot --root-namespace GWMyBot.Database  
Using assembly 'GWMyBot.Database'.  
Using startup assembly 'GWMyBot'.  
Using application base 'C:\Users\parab\Source\Repos\GWMyBot\GWMyBot\bin\Debug\netcoreapp2.2'.  
Using working directory 'C:\Users\parab\Source\Repos\GWMyBot\GWMyBot'.  
Using root namespace 'GWMyBot.Database'.  
Using project directory 'C:\Users\parab\Source\Repos\GWMyBot\GWMyBot.Database\'.  
Finding DbContext classes...  
Finding IDesignTimeDbContextFactory implementations...  
Finding application service provider...  
Finding Microsoft.Extensions.Hosting service provider...  
No static method 'CreateHostBuilder(string[])' was found on class 'Program'.  
No application service provider was found.  
Finding DbContext classes in the project...  
Found DbContext 'MyContext'.  
Using context 'MyContext'.
```

I've let this just sit for nearly an hour, nothing happens.

Comment: Make sure you set a startup project on your solution.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same issue when trying to add a migration after changing the base class from `DbContext` to `IdentityDbContext`.

It was due to a mismatch in the references for `Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity.EntityFrameworkCore`.

Project was on .Net Core 5 prev 7 but I mistakenly added a reference in NuGet for 3.1.

Comment: I forgot to mention it but I did see your earlier issue and unfortunately, we are using DbContext instead of IdentityDbContext. Thanks.